# MapStruct : Conditional mapping of object property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct in springboot application for mapping StudentBean(source) to StudentDTO(target).
I want to map properties on condition basis, conditions are as below :

**Condition 1:** If target(StudentDTO) property has value then don't map from source(StudentBean) property.

**Condition 2:** If source(StudentBean)property has value then only map into target(StudentDTO)else target value should not be updated.

Source class as below :

```
StudentBean{
String id;
int marks;
}
```

Target class as below :

```
StudentDTO{
String id;
int marks;
}
```

Mapper class as below :

```
@Mapper
Interface studentMapper{
@mapping(target="id", source="id")// apply condition 1
@mapping(target="marks", source="marks")// apply condition 2
StudentDTO toDTO(StudentBean);
}

How to achieve this with mapstruct?
```

Answer (score 3):

From the conditions you described, I assume you want to map a source StudentBean to an **existing** StudentDTO target, otherwise, your first condition will not make sense. You can read more about mapping to existing bean from Mapstruct documentation [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances).

Your **condition 2** can be easily achieved by setting `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE` on the `@Mapping` annotation. This setting will let Mapstruct ignore the mapping if the source's propeties are null.

Your **condition 1** is a little bit tricky, but it can be achieved with the newest feature [Conditional Mapping](https://mapstruct.org/news/2021-07-18-mapstruct-1_5_0_Beta1-is-out/#conditional-mapping) in `1.5.0.Beta1` release. Please note this feature is only available in **beta** release at this moment.

Your mapper would be set up and written like below:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

mapper

```
@Mapper
Interface studentMapper{
    @Mapping(conditionExpression = "java(studentDTO.getId() == null)", target="id", source="id", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    @Mapping(target="marks", source="marks", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    StudentDTO toExistingStudentDTO(StudentBean studentBean, @MappingTarget StudentDTO studentDTO);
}
```

`conditionExpression` property on the first @Mapping is available in the beta release. The `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE` setting is also set on this mapping because otherwise Mapstruct will set id to null by default if the condition in `conditionExpression` is not met.